# Install SharePoint 2013 client sdk in SQL production

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sdk

I am not a SharePoint person so please bear with me on my question.  I have been asked to install the SharePoint 2013 Client Component SDK in a production SQL environment.  I have been trying to research if there are negatives to doing this and cannot find that this is a common thing to do.  Since SDKs are usually used for development and in almost 20 years of managing SQL Servers I have never been asked to install SDKs in a production environment I am thinking that this is not a good idea.  Anyone have advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Client SDK of SharePoint 2013 deploy DLLs in the GAG of your server.
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll (as far as i remember) and some others **client** DLLs. So, there should not be any conflict with other MS product.

But, this sdk is needed by client application for SharePoint. Which means, you need to install a client SharePoint Application on a SQL server. If there is no problem with this. There is no problem with your install of the SDK.

PS: Client application for SharePoint can connect To SharePoint system everywhere (server, PC,..) so you can install this apps on an other server (or PC). but it depends on what the application makes
(sorry for my english)